# How to prevent users from creating new tables/stored procedures or modifying existing procedures. SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

Is there a way to lock down (preferably at the server level but DB level is also fine) tables and stored procedures? I don't want specific users creating new procedures or tables, but want them to be able to write to tables (via some Excel macros we have in place) and execute existing procedures. I would not want this to be a blanket policy, I'd prefer to specify which users this applies to.

Comment: Your users have the permissions you assign - nothing else. If you do not give them permission to create a table, they cannot create tables. So - what permissions have you granted?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have individual ms SQL server logins for every user? Then you can set the access rights of these to Datareader and datawriter only in the security section or on database level.

If everyone uses the same login, you will have to create trigger on the data definition level. E.g. a trigger on CREATE TABLE that aborts any action.

Edit: I suggest you create a new login specifically for those excel  macros.

Comment: Every user has their own logins with windows authentication and when they use the macros they are passing through their own login

Comment: I have an app where the vendor uses a single login do to everything. So when I needed to have them use excel data sources, I created a new login with rights restricted accordingly and a right granted for the stored procedure.

Comment: @ExpertGoogler Are those logins used for a 3rd party software? Then they might need the existing rights as are.